# Generate number of search requests over a given year

Tags: google-search-appliance

Does anyone know if there is a way to generate a report that details how many search requests the GSA has handled over a given timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

On the admin console: Reports > Search Logs.

Select the appropriate collection or All Collections.

Select the desired date range for the Report Timeframe.

From memory this only has access to a max 90 days historical data though so if you haven't been regularly exporting this data than you'll need to extrapolate the values from what is available.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @BigMikeW Logs only retain data for 90 days. Unless you download every 90 days, you wont get it.
Other way is **integration with Google Analytics** and pass all search data to GA search behavior. That way you can use GA to play around and export for a year or even more. This is what I use.